# Parse Linux static Libraries (.a) in C

Tags: c, linux, parsing, unix, .a

I want to know how to parse a linux static librarie (.a) to get content of each files.
Thank's to help me !

Comment: What does "parsing the content of a static library" means to you? You might want to use `objdump`

Comment: There is `ar` utility that does it. Is it homework?

Comment: This is a very general question, what kind of information do you want from the libraries?

But to answer it partly. .a files are archived files. A good start is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29

You should really look at the source code of ar. You can grab a copy of binutils.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `objdump` mentioned, you can use `nm` to list the content of a dot-a file, both what is defined inside (as well as which file.c defined them, when not stripped), as well as extern (which needs to be satisfied by other libraries).